# Regarding Yii CMarkdown Class

Tags: php, yii, markdown

I want to display some text in a `CDetailView` which was previously encoded in **MarkDown** format.

this is my view code:

```
<?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'title',
    array(
                'name'=>'text',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>$this->markdown->transform($model->text)
            ),
    'author_id',
    'date_added',
),
)); 
?>
```

**and** in my controller, I instantiate a `CMarkDown` filter like this:

```
    private $_markdown = null;

    public function getMarkdown()
    {
            if ( $this->_markdown === null)
            {
                    $this->_markdown = new CMarkdown();
                    $this->_markdown->purifyOutput = true;
            }
            return $this->_markdown;
    }
```

notice how I explicitly set `purifyOutput` to `true`.

So I created a mock post full of things like marquee and injected javascript to see how it would behave and it didn't filter anything at all!! I got an alert on my face and the marquee was all happy moving around on the page....

I found a workaround which was to set `'type'=>'html'` in the `CDetailView` but I shouldn't need to do that, should I??

Isn't that `purifyOutput` option supposed to filter unwanted stuff out for me when I call the `->transform()` method??

Some help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To purify the output you need to use `CMarkdown::processOutput`, not the `transform` method (that one is more low-level and does not honor `purifyOutput`).

If you look at the documentation carefully, you will notice that `processOutput` [mentions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMarkdown#processOutput-detail) the `purifyOutput` setting while `transform` [does not](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMarkdown#transform-detail). Viewing the source confirms this.